# How do I properly use the json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I want to send data from php to a browser using JSON. I think I understand the process - see my example code below. But someone told me this is not the right way to do it. I have been researching for three days but because my English is poor I am not confident that I have found an answer.

What I am hoping for is a sample of code that will receive the JSON and pour it into html elements such as a div, and give it style via CSS, etc.

I really just want an example of how to do this so that I can learn from it and expand it myself for my own needs, but I am unconfident that this approach is correct and do not want to write more bad code.

Thanks

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        dataType:"json",
        success : function (data) { 
            $("#orders").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }); 
});
```

PHP

```
<?php 
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
    $statement=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM myfeilds");
    $statement->execute();
    $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $json=json_encode($results);
    echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: try with type: application/json

Comment: So what's your exact question?

Comment: Looks just fine, and is exactly the way you'd return JSON to an ajax function. If you want to output it nicer with styles etc. you'd have to use more than one element, and create some sort of system.

Comment: i can not this work please edit my cod and send to answer

Comment: Are you trying to show a table with the results? You cannot simply ‘translate’ JSON to HTML; you need to loop through the items in the response and create a table row for each. Begin with ditching the `JSON.stringify(data)`; you are already receiving JSON data.

Comment: BTW, Stack Overflow is not meant for answering your study exercises. We are not going to write free code for you … :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'server.php',
        dataType:"application/json",
        success : function (data) { 
           var jsns=JSON.parse(data);
           $("#orders").html("");//clear the div
           for(var i in data)
           {
             var id = data[i].id;
             var name = data[i].name;
             $("#orders").append("<span>"+id+"-"+name+</span>);//append each element
           }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Since your server side php is already returning json.. you can just loop through the array of objects after converting it into JSON and then do DOM manipulation.

The best way to do it would be to use some templating engine like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

Comment: Thanks @Raj for providing something - I edited the OP's question as his original was a little difficult to read. Glad he got an acceptable answer.